# rspec undefined method `receive' for expect syntax

Tags: rspec

Changing tests that work such as:

```
describe "a" do
  it "does part A" do
    it "does not wait if not run in parallel" do
      ParallelTests.should_not_receive(:sleep)
      ParallelTests.wait_for_other_processes_to_finish
    end
  end
end
```

to

```
describe "a" do
  it "does not wait if not run in parallel" do
    expect(ParallelTests).to_not receive(:sleep)
    ParallelTests.wait_for_other_processes_to_finish
  end
end
```

gives

```
 Failure/Error: expect(ParallelTests).to_not receive(:sleep)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `receive' for 
 #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_3:0x00000002874158>
```

This is an example.  Happens in many places, common theme is that it's always about changing `.should_receive` to `expect().to receive`

Gemfile has version of rspec at 2.4

How to fix?

Comment: Your error is for a different example.

Comment: Corrected.  Was just trying to squeeze in smaller text to avoid line breaks.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your entire spec (or at least all the elements that apply to the `expect` statement (e.g. enclosing `it` and `describe` blocks)?

Comment: Your first example isn't formed properly. `it` is undefined within an `it` block. Are you sharing the exact code that has passed?

Comment: What version of RSpec are you using?

Comment: That's it!  Default on my machine was 2.13.  This syntax needs 2.14  Weird thing is the Gemfile had 2.4 and even if I did `bundle exec` I still got the error.  In the end I removed all versions of rspec from my machine (I had about 10) and then changed the Gemfile from `2.4` to `2.14`

Comment: That's actually not wierd, but expected.  See updated answer.

Comment: Well it seemed a bit weird that I had several hundred other tests that I was able to convert to `expect` without issue.  The issue seemed specific with expect().to receive`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use of the `expect` syntax for message expectations was introduced in RSpec 2.14, per http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2013/07/rspec-2-14-is-released. (Note: RSpec 2.4 is ten minor versions *earlier* than RSpec 2.14, per the recommended http://semver.org/.)

Change the Gemfile to be 2.14, e.g. `gem 'rspec', '2.14'` and do `bundle`